# Deleting a record through a join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm sure this has been answered hundreds of times, but I have searched and tried 100 things this morning so I am just going to ask the question. Feel free to just link me to another post...

I have 3 models: Notes, Tags, NoteTags (join)

Notes have many tags, tags have many notes; I'm trying to destroy a Note, the NoteTag link is being destroyed but the Tags remain.

Models:

```
class Note < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :note_tags
  has_many :tags, -> { uniq }, through: :note_tags, dependent: :destroy
end

class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :note_tags
  has_many :notes, through: :note_tags, dependent: :destroy
end

class NoteTag < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :note
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

So, obviously if the Tag still has a different note that has it, I don't want it to be deleted.. but if it's no longer featured in the note_tag table, it should be removed...

Is there any way of doing this?!

Thanks

Comment: as per my understanding you want if a note destroyed than its related tags should also destroy . right ?

Comment: This is not what I'm experiencing with the code above!

Comment: what you want ?

Comment: When I delete a Note, for any tags that are no longer associated with any note in the join table to be deleted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could destroy orphan tags after destroying the note.

```
def destroy
  @note = Note.find_by(id: params[:id])
  if @note
    @note.destroy_with_tags
  end
end

def destroy_with_tags
  oldtag_ids = tag_ids
  destroy
  Tag.find(oldtag_ids).each do |tag|
    tag.destroy if tag.notes == []
  end
end
```

There may be other more efficient approach, in case the number of tags is big.

**Second approach (currently not working)**

Use the normal destroy and add a callback to destroy orphan tags.
This option does not work, but might work with some changes I could not test.

```
class Note << ApplicationRecord
  before_destroy :old_tags
  after_destroy :destroy_orphan_tags

  def old_tags
    @oldtag_ids = tag_ids
  end

  def destroy_orphan_tags
    #Destroy tags that were associated to this note, if there are no more notes
    Tag.find(@oldtag_ids).joins(:note_tags).group('tags.id').having("count (*) = 0").destroy_all
  end
end
```

Comment: Ah interesting - I'll give that a go. I find it pretty odd that this behaviour requires additional methods... seems like very obvious functionality! Thanks for your help tho.

Comment: I added a second option with a before_destroy callback (so your controller needs no changes; just @note.destroy). But you should test if it works and some changes may be needed.

Comment: This is close I think but it doesn't work.. after a bit of debugging I think it's because the tags in oldtags think they are still associated with the note, even after it has been destroyed? Maybe they are copied into the variable and still have that association?

Comment: ah ok I'll try that - my comment is aimed at your first solution

Comment: This is giving a `wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)` error - there is an errant ( before having, but I removed that. I also tried group instead of group_by but that also didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Regarding you comment "this is close" maybe you could do `tag.reload` before tag.destroy. I will check the error in your last comment. Where is the error happening? Can you post all the error message?

Comment: ```ArgumentError in NotesController#destroy

wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

Extracted source (around line #11):
              
  def destroy_orphan_tags

    #Destroy tags with only one note (the note that is going to be destroyed)

    tags.joins(:note_tags).group_by('tags.id').having("count (*) = 1").destroy

  end

end
```

Comment: I can't get either of these two solutions to work. This is just so frustrating, I don't understand - surely this is functionality everyone wants?! Are there loads of blogs out there with orphaned tags just floating around after posts are deleted? I don't get it! This doesn't seem like a niche requirement.

Comment: Just changed destroy by destroy_all, as the method is applied to tags collection (not only 1 tag). Please, check if it works.

Comment: I tried with tag.reload.. it doesn't seem to work... but if I use Pry and do it step by step, the exact same code, then it does work... what's the deal with that!?

Comment: So i'm now getting `PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR: update or delete on table "tags" violates foreign key constraint` ... probably because the tags are being deleted before the note?

Comment: I did another try. Check it (and sorry :))

Comment: Hi - don't be sorry, I appreciate your help! However, this doesn't work. In the destroy_orphan_tags method, `@oldtags` is empty (I had to change it to `@oldtags` in both methods to access it from destroy_orphan_tags)

Comment: Sorry. My fault. Even after calling it @oldtags they are empty?

Comment: yep as far as I can tell...

```[1] pry(#<Note>)> @oldtags
  Tag Load (0.4ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "note_tags" ON "tags"."id" = "note_tags"."tag_id" WHERE "note_tags"."note_id" = $1  [["note_id", 82]]
=> []
```

Comment: Another shot. Saving only tag_ids. Check the new version :)

Comment: I think the `joins(:note_tags).group('tags.id').having("count (*) = 0").destroy_all` bit has to change more - at the moment it's saying `TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into String)` and I think it's to do with the join...

Comment: Sorry. I'm writing options but cannot test them. What is @oldtag_ids value now?

Comment: I updated the first option to use `oldtag_ids`. This method does not use the join, so you could give a try

Comment: IT WORRRRKKKKSSSS!

Comment: had to change `unless tag.notes` to `if tag.notes == []` for... reasons... but the important thing is it WOOOOORRRKKS. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Finally!. I updated the answer so that it has the latest version, that is working. You can make a few more tests just to be sure and then accept the answer :). Good luck